# add icons in actions columns and in each row - react admin

Tags: react-admin

I want to add a column on List in react admin and it has to have two actions. Now, each action is a column and I can't add a header title.

For example:

```
<List>
   <Datagrid>
           <TextField label="Id" source="order.id" />
           <DateField label="Inicio" source="startDate" />
           <CheckIcon
            color="action"
            onClick={(e) => confirmOrder(e)}
           />
           <CancelIcon
            color="action"
            onClick={(e) => cancelOrder(e)}
           />
   </Datagrid>
</List>
```

I want to create a column "Actions" and add both CheckIcon and CancelIcon.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them inside a custom field:

```
const OrderActions = () => (
    <>
        <IconButton onClick={(e) => confirmOrder(e)}>
            <CheckIcon color="action" />
        <IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={(e) => cancelOrder(e)}>
            <CancelIcon color="action" />
        <IconButton>
    </>
)
```

Then:

```
<List>
   <Datagrid>
           <TextField label="Id" source="order.id" />
           <DateField label="Inicio" source="startDate" />
           <OrderActions />
   </Datagrid>
</List>
```